# Binary Search Seg Fault

Tags: c, search, recursion, binary

I'm trying to implement a binary search in a slightly non-traditional way by using only 3 arguments int value (what I'm looking for), int values[] (the array), int n (the size of the array). The code below finds the number 2 and recognizes that 13 is not there, but cannot find numbers like 6 or 7.  I think the problem is in the final recursive call. It could be a pointer issue. I'm certain the rest of the code works fine. Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool search(int value, int values[], int n);

int main(void)
{   
    int value = 6;
    int values[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int n = 7;

    bool x = search(value, values, n);

    if (x == true)
        printf("found\n");
    else
        printf("not found\n");
}

bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    int midpoint = n/2;

    if (n/2 <= 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (value == values[midpoint])
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (value < values[midpoint])
    {
        return search(value, values, n/2);
    }
    else if (value > values[midpoint])
    {
        return search(value, values, n/2);
    }

 return false;
}
```

Comment: You need something like `values + n - n/2` (which is not the same as `values + n/2`).

Comment: I'm note sure that I follow, since values is the name of the array.  Adding the quantity n/2 doesn't seem like it would make sense. I'll certainly play around with it though. Many thanks for the reply!

Comment: The line `if (n/2 <= 0)` is wrong. 0 is a valid array index. That is why your code cannot find any value at the beginning of an array slice.

Comment: Your logic is completely wrong, passing (n/2) won't work. If the searching element is in right half part of array, your code goes looking into left half part of array. There is no difference between last if and else condition lines.

Comment: @RyanD. `values` is an array in `main`. It's a pointer in `search`, and so you can make adjustments to the pointer. Your code is always searching the first half of the array. To make it search the last half, you need to adjust the pointer to point at the last half.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for the clarification. The underlying problem was slightly more complex than I thought!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that when you call search with the upper half of the array, you should pass it with the offset like

```
return search(value, values + (n + 1) / 2, n / 2);
```

Note that I also skipped the middle element that you have already compared for the cases when `n` is odd. You can of course optimize the recursive calls, always taking care that also the length is calculated correctly.

Comment: This has problem too.